# podman container MySQL container - access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: dockerfile, podman, buildah

I am building a MySQL image using `buildah bud -f .podman/MySQL.conf -t localhost/mysql:mushroom` and the following dockerfile (located at .podman/MYSQL.conf)

```
    FROM mysql:8.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='password'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    EXPOSE 3306
```

I start the container using: 
`podman run --rm -v mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql localhost/mysql:mushroom` 

After starting the container I `podman exe -it [ID] /bin/bash`  into the container cli.
running `mysql -p` and entering the correct password returns `access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I have confirmed that the env var MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD is correctly set.
I have tried entering the password in the podman run command (using `-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password`) I have confirmed that the volume `mysql_data` doesn't exist when I start the container.

Any suggestions for other things to try?

Comment: Did you check if the password variable is sourced (loaded into shell context)? `env | grep "MYSQL"`

Comment: @ja0nz yes, I did

Answer (score 1):

All I can say is that it seems to work for me.

I used your example Dockerfile (the only thing I did was to trim all the whitespace it seems to have accidentally gained when you pasted it).

I saved it as `Dockerfile` and then just used `podman build .`.

Starting the image in one terminal with `podman run 8a0516eaa26e` prints a load of log lines showing mysql startup and then ends with

```
[System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

In another terminal I ran `podman exec -it happy_dijkstra /bin/bash` (that was the auto-generated container name I got) and tried to login to mysql with "password" and it worked. I have podman v3.4.2 here, but I would expect something as simple as this to have worked since v1. Are you sure there isn't a space or other odd character that has sneaked into the password you set?

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked after a reboot.
My best guess is that the mysql_data volume still existed somehow, and held default login data.